# How do I format a cell based on cells in a column that is not empty?

Tags: excel, vba

This is really simple but I'm new to VBA.

I want to format cells in column J and K (haven't gotten to K yet) with a grey fill and border around if cells in column B is not empty. I want to do this in every worksheet in the workbook.

```
Sub forEachWs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Format_ForecastingTemplate(ws)
    Next
End Sub


Sub Format_ForecastingTemplate(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        If cell <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells("J"), cell.Row)
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The line that is giving me an error is `If cell <> "" Then`. I think it's because I'm not referencing the `cell` variable in column B?

Error is: `Object variable or With block variable not set`

Like this:

[image: Like this:]

Comment: add `ws.` before `Cells()` to make sure it's using the `Cells()` on `ws`. Otherwise, it'll use the ActiveSheet.  Also, change `ActiveSheet` to `ws` as well, so it's using the `ws` in your loop, not whatever the activesheet happens to be.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: also use cell.value

Comment: Ah, also `Cells("J")` needs to be a number...`ws.Cells("J1").Value` for example.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad would conditional formatting be better in this case and as best practice?

Comment: *I* believe it is better, but I *also* believe that, to a certain extent, it is a matter of opinion. That said, it is a fact that circumstances will change what the best solution is likely to be, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to a single macro and made changes to your original code

```
Sub Format_ForecastingTemplate()

Dim cell As Range
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
    'Looks at B to check if empty
        If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
            'changes cells J to color and border
            ws.Cells(i, 10).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            ws.Cells(i, 10).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            ws.Cells(i, 10).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.25

        End If
    Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

You can either change the column number or add new lines for column K
Hope this helps and please be kind and leave feedback. :)

Comment: I didn't use your code exactly but it gave me some ideas. Thanks.